# UITableView doesn't scroll when used in "Tabbed Application"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I recently started my first project for iOS 5. I started with an empty preset, the so called "Tabbed Application". I inserted a `UITableView` in the main view. That `UITableView` doesn't scroll when I open it for the first time, but it does after switching to the second tab.

There's also an `UIBarButtonItem` that doesn't work, but I guess that's the same problem. I tried a lot, nothing seems to work. At first I thought that I did something wrong in my project, so I started a test-project… with the same problem.

Someone knows a way to fix this?

Comment: What did you mean with tab? UITabBarController?

Comment: Yes, made with the "Tabbed Application"-preset when creating the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `self.tableView.bounces = YES;` to your viewController's `viewDidLoad:` message?

Comment: That worked for the test project, where the `UITableView` was attached to the `view`-outlet of the File's Owner. In my own project, there's a `UIView` with the `UITableView` as a subview. In that case it didn't work. I needed that view to show the table with an `UINavivigationBar`.. Guess that's not the right way? The buttons in that navigation bar doesn't work either btw.